# Why object is changed when I dont touch that?

Tags: php, arrays, object

i use this code:

```
$source= (object) array('next'=>'hi', 'val'=>'bye');
$next= (object) array('val'=>'hello');
$source->next=$next;
    var_dump($next->val);       // <----------------------- outputs "hello"
$source->next->val = $source->val;
    var_dump($next->val);       // <----------------------- outputs "bye"
exit;
```

can you tell me, why the `$next` variable outputs different values (i mean, why it was touched at all??? i have not used `$next = ....` declaration there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On this line

```
$source->next=$next;
```

You are assigning address, so object are by default pass by address which point to `$source->next`.

when the first time you `var_dump($next->val)` -> its value hasn't changed yet, you just assign `$next` to `$source->next`.

But next line you are changing value of `$source->next->val`, which is pointing to `$next`. So value at `$next` variable will get change.

I hope I am clear, and this will help you.

Comment: yes, I didnt know that object, by default, was passed by address... I thought it was assigned to seperate variable..

Answer (score 0):

Here's the line where you did change it and quite explicitly.

```
$source->next->val = $source->val;
```